# In a card game. why does it make a difference if I draw cards simultaneously

Tags: probability, card-games

Four cards are successively drawn without replacement from a deck of 52 playing cards. What is the probability that all four cards are kings ?

There are two ways to approach this
i) There are $4$ favorable events out of $ ^{52}C_4$ events so the probability is
$\frac{4}{^{52}C_4}$

way two
there are $\frac{4}{52}$ ways of selecting the first card, $\frac{3}{51}$ dor the second and so on, which gives us a probability of $\frac{1}{270725}$.
why are there two different answers , and why is the $2^{nd}$ one right?

Comment: Why are there 4 favorable events out of $_{52}C_4$ events?

Comment: If the order of selection does not matter, there is only one way to draw four kings.

Comment: @Moko19, there are only 4 kngs

Comment: You still have not explained how you obtained $4$ favorable events in your first attempt.

Comment: there are 4 kings, so 4 possible cards

Comment: That would only make sense if you were choosing one card.  You are choosing all four kings.  There is only one way to select all four kings if the order of selection does not matter.

Comment: There is the one collection of kings: $\{K\clubsuit, K\diamondsuit, K\heartsuit, K\spadesuit\}$.  This is a single *collection*.  Yes, it happens to have four elements within the collection... but it is still just the one set.  There are no other sets with the four kings in them.  Remember also that in the context of sets, the order the elements are written within the set do not matter and so this is the same set as $\{K\spadesuit, K\diamondsuit, K\heartsuit, K\clubsuit\}$ for instance

Comment: As for order mattering or not mattering... you get to choose for yourself whatever makes more sense.  What matters is that you are *consistent* with your choice for both numerator and denominator, and that the events you are describing don't actually reference the exact order things occur.  If done correctly, the answers will come out to be the same both ways.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\text{Probability}=\frac{\binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{0}}{\binom{52}{4}}.
$$

Comment: why is this the answer and not $\frac{4}{^{52}C_4}$?

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever What other events do you think there are?  I can think of only the one event... the one where the four kings are all taken (*in some order*).  What second or third or fourth different event do you think there is where you draw the four kings and nothing else?

Comment: @math and physics forever, As you know the standard card deck has $4$ kings. We need to get those $4$ kings successively and, hence, other cards that are not equal to the king must not be, therefore, we will have that member (multiplier) $\binom{48}{0}$.

Comment: I see, thanks!!